# Why is CostFinalize modifying my custom property in one install and not the other?

Tags: wix, copy, wix3.7

I have two installs with virtually identical code. I set a custom property like this:

```
<SetProperty Id="MYCONFIGPATH" Value="[CONFIGPATH]" Before="CostInitialize"/>
```

And then reference that property in a component:

```
<Component Id="CopyConfigFromConfigPath" Guid="{XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}" MultiInstance="yes">
    <Condition>CONFIGPATH</Condition>
    <CopyFile SourceProperty="MYCONFIGPATH" DestinationDirectory="ConfigBOR" DestinationName="ConfigBOR.xml" Id="CopyConfigBOR" />
</Component>
```

I'm not certain this is what's causing the failure to copy this file but I suspect it is:

```
MSI (s) (64:6C) [14:03:42:383]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying MYCONFIGPATH property. Its current value is 'C:\Installs\ConfigBOR.xml'. Its new value: 'C:\Installs\ConfigBOR.xml\'.
```

Notice the trailing backslash. This happens shortly after starting `CostFinalize`. Just above that log entry are some suspicious looking entries but I can't figure out what they mean so I'm not sure they're relevant:

```
MSI (s) (64:6C) [14:03:42:380]: Doing action: CostFinalize
MSI (s) (64:6C) [14:03:42:380]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText
```

and

```
MSI (s) (64:6C) [14:03:42:382]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Patch 
MSI (s) (64:6C) [14:03:42:383]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Condition
```

I have identical code in another installer (BOR is replaced with the product name in that one) but it doesn't modify this property and does correctly copy this file. Why doesn't it work here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C:\Installs\ConfigBOR.xml` did not exist. I guess WIX picked up on that and, instead of throwing an error, decided to check if a directory with that name were present.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your question provides enough information to answer this for certain, but my [psychic powers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/18/760789.aspx) tell me that `MYCONFIGPATH` is in the [Directory table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368295.aspx) in one package but not in the other. Thus the directory resolution phase of [CostFinalize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368048.aspx) affects the two packages differently.